# why does local_variables return local variables that have not been assigned?

Tags: ruby

Why does `local_variables` return local variables that have not been assigned yet (assigned after the invocation of `local_variables`)?

```
a = 2
@aa = 1
# a = b # this will raise an error.
puts "local: #{ local_variables }"
puts "instance: #{ instance_variables }"

b = 2
@bb = 2
puts "local: #{ local_variables }"
puts "instance: #{ instance_variables }"
```

result:

```
local: [:a, :b]
instance: [:@aa]
local: [:a, :b]
instance: [:@aa, :@bb]
```

What I expect is the behaviour like `instance_variables`, that only returns variables that have already been assigned in that moment.

Comment: i think puts statements are executed after the assignments are done,
statements are not executed by line number serial.

Comment: Could you please exit your IRB and try the same?

Comment: If `puts` is executed after the assignments then `instance_variable` will behave the same, so it's may not like your say.

Answer (score 1):

[`Kernel#local_variables`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-local_variables) lists all local variables that are in the current scope, including those that may not have been assigned a value yet. [MRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_MRI) parses the locals variables in each scope and declares them before the code itself (such as `puts local_variables.inspect` below) runs, so they show up even when `local_variables` is called before those variables have been defined

But note that `defined?` still returns `nil` for variables that have not yet been assigned to when `local_variables` is called:

```
$ cat /tmp/locals
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

a = 5
puts local_variables.inspect
puts defined?(a)
puts (defined?(b) || "[undefined]")
b = 10
puts defined?(b)

def foo
  c = 15
  puts local_variables.inspect
  d = 20
end
foo

$ ruby /tmp/locals
[:a, :b]
local-variable
[undefined]
local-variable
[:c, :d]
```

Comment: But why ruby designed like this, is there some reason? Isn't it counterintuitive? And how can I get the "real" local variables that have been assigned at the moment I want?

Comment: Someone may prove me wrong, but testing that dynamically is not possible in Ruby as you cannot pass strings or symbols containing variable names to `defined?`. It's designed so for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby [creates local variables at compile time](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/155673#685906). Instance variables are clearly bound to the instance and can be accessed easily. However, `b` could be:

1. A method call
2. `self.b`
3. the local variable `b`

Have a look at [Brian Candler's response here (Google cache)](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aaEB1UxO-V1IJ%3agroups.google.com/group/ruby-talk-google/browse_thread/thread/b36a49bb4944baf9+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk). That's also the reason why you cannot create local variables at runtime with eval.